# What keywords should I use in parental control to block Facebook on Android app and iPhone apps?

Tags: router, android, iphone, facebook, parental-controls

I need to block Facebook in my WiFi by my tp-link archer C6 router. Using parental control I able to block on desktop but not in apps on Android and iPhone.

Comment: That is something you need to work out for yourself.

Comment: What model is the router?

Comment: I don't know that parental controls will work for this. Mobile devices will likely encrypt traffic leaving them, and certainly the apps on them will, making it difficult for a parental control system on the router to be able to identify the traffic in question. If you're trying to control children's devices, you should look into tools and settings appropriate for this. Both Apple and Google offer these, native to the devices. In general, blocking this on the device itself is more effective.

Comment: After researching internet at last I am successful to block Facebook. First input these keywords to the block address of your router.

facebook.com, 
m.facebook.com, 
fbcdn.com, 
fbcdn.net, 
fb.com, 
fb.me, 
akamaihd.net, 
fbsbx.com, 
fburl.com, 
freebasics.com, 
internet.org, 
m.me

Now go to Facebook and messenger apps settings of your mobile. delete all data. ok done.
Otherwise, wait for a week it will block Facebook within this period. I don't know why!